# how to do row/column change?

Tags: soql

In my scenario, i am facing row/column change problem. But, i don't know how to do it. In salesforce, my object store some student values, just like

[image]

i want to change display this table with following:

[image]

how to do this use apex + vf page? or how to write this soql?

Comment: Can you please put some effort in writing the question and visualise the representation?

Comment: I have no any idea to address this issue. i search some information from Google. And i know this row/column in oracle have api support. but, i don't find any api in soql? so, if you know it, please tell me how to address this issue. Many thanks

Comment: What is your object name that contains these records? Also what type of field is "Subject"? Is it a lookup to another object or just a picklist?

Comment: The object is my customer object and the name is TestGrade. Student/subject column type is text field. grade type is Int. Subject is picklist values.

Comment: There is no standard functionality that will help you achieve this. You need to do a bit of data mapping in APEX and some custom HTML + JS/JQUery code that will handle the displaying of the table in the VF page. By providing the data model structure including the object & field names, you might get an example answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display in the second format, you can use wrapper class concept,

first construct a wrapper class like below

```
     public class wrapperOne{
      public String StudentName{get;set;}
      public Integer History{get;set;}
      public Integer  Math{get;set;}
      public Integer  Chinese{get;set;}  
      public Integer   sport{get;set;}    
     }
```

Create one list of wrapper

```
Public List<wrapperOne> wraperList {get;set;}
```

Query from the original table

```
     wraperList  = new List<wrapperOne>();
     for(Student str: [Select id, name,History,Math,chinese,sport from student]){
     wrapperOne wraStr = new wrapperOne();
     wraStr.studentName =str.name;
     wraStr.Math=str.Math;
     wraStr.chinese=str.chinese;
     wraStr.History=str.History;
     wraStr.sport =str.sport ;
     wraperList.add(wraStr);}
```

Use this one in cf repeat

```
<apex:dataTable value={!wraperList} var="wra">
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
 {!wra.StudentName}
</apex:column>
 <apex:column headerValue="History">
 {!wra.History}
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Math">
 {!wra.Math}
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Chinese">
 {!wra.Chinese}
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Sport">
 {!wra.Sport}
</apex:column>
```

Comment: i am facing the similar kind of issue but rather than Stundent as a picklist it is a Master-detail relation ship. So i dont knw who many relations will be there.. in that case how can you do it? any idea?